# A fair coin is tossed 50 times. The outcome is written in order. Compute the expected number of occurrences of "HHH"(with overlaps allowed)

Tags: probability

A fair coin is tossed 50 times. The outcome is written in order. Compute the expected number of occurrences of "HHH"(with overlaps allowed).

For example "THHHHTTHHHTH" has 3 such occurrences.

I was trying to work through this problem, but the overlaps is what makes it a bit tricky. Because if it's separate 3 Hs in a row then I can just set X to be the RV representing the number of "HHH" then get the probability for all the possible ones from 1 to floor(50/3) then multiply the probabilities by X and sum and be done, but the overlaps make it so this won't work.

Comment: Use linearity.  Overlaps don't matter (linearity works even for dependent variables).

Comment: How would I apply it in this case?

Comment: Set indicator variables.  For for $i\in \{1,\cdots, n-2\}$ let $X_i=1$ if a $HHH$ block starts at slot $i$ and $X_i=0$ otherwise (Note:  I am assuming the string has length $n$).  Then linearity tells us that the answer, $E$, is given by $E=E\big [\sum X_i\big ]=\sum E[X_i]$

Comment: How do I calculate the probability of $X_i$? Because it's the probability of 3 HHHs at that index yes? Doesn't that mean we have to do "HHH" there and any combination of "HHH"s before that too yes?

Comment: Or would that just be $(1/2)^3*(1/2)^{i-1}$?

Comment: I don't understand.  The probability that the $i^{th},(i+1)^{st},(i+2)^{nd}$ tosses are all $H$ is obviously $\frac 18$.  It does not depend on $i$.